# How long long is represented in memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, bitwise-operators

I am not an advanced C++ programmer. But I have been using C++ for a long time now. So, I love playing with it. Lately I was thinking about ways to maximize a variable programmatically. So I tried **Bitwise Operators** to fill a variable with **1**'s. Then there's `signed` and `unsigned` issue. My knowledge of memory representation is not very well. However, I ended up writing the following code which is working for both `signed` and `unsigned` `short`, `int` and `long` (although `int` and `long` are basically the same). Unfortunately, for `long` `long`, the program is failing.

So, what is going on behind the scenes for `long` `long`? How is it represented in memory? Besides, Is there any better way to do achieve the same thing in C++?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;



template<typename T>
void Maximize(T &val, bool isSigned)
{
    int length = sizeof(T) * 8;
    cout << "\nlength = " << length << "\n";

    // clearing
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        val &= 0 << i;
    }

    if(isSigned)
    {
        length--;
    }

    val = 1 << 0;
    for(int i=1; i<length; i++)
    {
        val |= 1 << i;

        cout << "\ni = " << i << "\nval = " << val << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    long long i;

    Maximize(i, true);

    cout << "\n\nsizeof(i) = " << sizeof(i) << " bytes" << "\n";
    cout << "i = " << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a simple question, have a read of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: If a `long long` is 64 bits, which is the most common, then it's 64 consecutive bits in memory. If you know the binary numbering system then you know how it's represented in memory (well, except the issue of *endianness* as mentioned above).

Comment: @RichardCritten I have also thought that Endians may be to blame. But how do I know which one my PC is using?

Comment: If you're using a "PC" then it's most likely an x86-variant processor, which means it's little-endian.

Comment: That clearing loop is really pointless, you can just set `val` to zero (which is what the first iteration does anyway). Also `1` is not a `long long`. There is no endianness problem because you do not access the bytes separately.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am confused if there's a sign bit after each byte or just one at the MSB.

Comment: Just a single one.

Comment: I'm not sure what the right "C++-style" for this is but perhaps something like `(T)1 << i`?

Comment: @harold Yeah!!! It did work. Any better ways than this you know of?

Comment: I second @harold's comment. Endianness is a red herring. Endianness is only a factor if you access a value's bytes individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic issue with your code is in the statements

```
val &= 0 << i;
```

and

```
val |= 1 << i;
```

in the case that `val` is longer than an `int`.

In the first expression, `0 << i` is (most likely) always 0, regardless of `i` (technically, it suffers from the same undefined behaviour described below, but you will not likely encounter the problem.) So there was no need for the loop at all; all of the statements do the same thing, which is to zero out `val`. Of course, `val = 0;` would have been a simpler way of writing that.

The issue `1 << i` is that the constant literal `1` is an `int` (because it is small enough to be represented as an `int`, and `int` is the narrowest representation used for integeral constants). Since `1` is an `int`, so is `1 << i`. If `i` is greater than or equal to the number of value bits in an `int`, that expression has undefined behaviour, so in theory the result could be anything. In practice, however, the result is likely to be the same width as an `int`, so only the low-order bits will be affected.

It is certainly possible to convert the `1` to type `T` (although in general, you might need to be cautious about corner cases when `T` is signed), but it is easier to convert the `1` to an unsigned type at least as wide as `T`by using the maximum-width unsigned integer type defined in `cstdint`, `uintmax_t`:

```
val |= std::uintmax_t(1) << i;
```

In real-world code, it is common to see the assumption that the widest integer type is `long long`:

```
val |= 1ULL << i;
```

which will work fine if the program never attempts to instantiate the template with a extended integer type.

---

Of course, this is not the way to find the largest value for an integer type. The correct solution is to `#include <limits>` and then use the appropriate specialization of [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

---

C++ allows only one representation for positive (and unsigned) integers, and three possible representations for negative signed integers. Positive and unsigned integers are simply represented as a sequence of bits in binary notation. There may be padding bits as well, and signed integers have a single sign bit which must be 0 in the case of positive integers, so there is no guarantee that there are `8*sizeof(T)` useful bits in the representation, even if the number of bits in a byte is known to be 8 (and, in theory, it could be larger). [Note 1]

The sign bit for negative signed integers is always 1, but there are three different formats for the value bits. The most common is "two's complement", where the value bits interpreted as a positive number would be exactly 2<sup>k</sup> more than the actual value of the number, where `k` is the number of value bits. (This is equivalent to specifying a weight of 2<sup>-k</sup> to the sign bits, which is why it is called 2s complement.)

Another alternative is "one's complement", in which the value bits are all inverted individually. This differs by exactly one from two's-complement representation.

The third allowable alternative is "sign-magnitude", in which the value bits are precisely the absolute value of the negative number. This representation is frequently used for floating point values, but only rarely used in integer values.

Both sign-magnitude and one's complement suffer from the disadvantage that there is a bit pattern which represents "negative 0". On the other hand, two's complement representation has the feature that the magnitude of the most negative representable value is one larger than the magnitude of the most positive representable value, with the result that both `-x` and `x/-1` can overflow, leading to undefined behaviour.

---

#### Notes

1. I believe that it is theoretically possible for padding to be inserted between the value bits and the sign bits, but I certainly do not know of any real-world implementation with that feature. However, the fact that attempting to shift a 1 into the sign bit position is undefined behaviour makes it incorrect to assume that the sign bit is contiguous with the value bits.

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking about ways to maximize a variable programmatically.

You are trying to reinvent the wheel. C++ STL already has this functionality: [std::numeric_limits::max()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/?kw=numeric_limits)

```
// x any kind of numeric type: any integer or any floating point value
x = std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::max();
```

This is also better since you will not relay on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As **harold** commented, the solution is to use `T(1) << i` instead of `1 << i`. Also as **Some programmer dude** mentioned, `long` `long` is represented as consecutive bytes (typically 8 bytes) with sign bit at the MSB if it is `signed`.